# android in-app billing - any way to identify which version is being used

Tags: android, in-app-billing

am new to this in-app billing concept
on android developer page - they say that you should use version 3 of their api as version 2 will not be supported early 2015

Now my question is - is there a definite way to identify if I am using version 3 or version 2 ?

There are many examples of in-app billing -

I dont want to spend effort on an implementation only to later find that it is version 2 :(

as an example - I was referring to this link and have my in-app logic built :

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

Thanks
shankar

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a definite way to identify if you are using version 3 or version 2 Android In-app billing. If you are using in-app billing version 3, the version information is not directly returned the Google Play. Instead, you can check if Google Play supports the version of the In-app Billing API that you are using by sending a isBillingSupported request. In-app Billing Version 3 provides a new Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) file named IInAppBillingService.aidl. See this [In-app Billing Version Notes](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html) for more information.