# how can I add the aidl file to Android studio (from the in-app billing example)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aidl

I am currently migrating an Eclipse app to Android Studio.
This app was using the in app billing.

My main problem is to compile the project and the aidl file (I guess you all use [this file](http://stuff.mit.edu:8001/afs/sipb.mit.edu/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/play_billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl))

I get this error message:

```
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class IInAppBillingService
Gradle: error: package IInAppBillingService does not exist
```

So, following some tutorials, I move this file from com.mypackage.billing to src/main/aidl
(see [this reference](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56328))

But as soon, as I do that, I get this message:

> Gradle: Execution failed for task ':xxxxxxxxxxx:compileDebugAidl'.
>
> > Failed to run command:
> >             (...)     C:\Users\xxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\xxxxxxProject\xxxxxxx\src\main\aidl\IInAppBillingService.aidl:45
> >     interface IInAppBillingService should be declared in a file called
> >     com\xxxxxxxx\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl.

The message is clearly a contradiction with the post from the Google bug page I linked above.

Anyone suceeded to make this aidl file to work and can help me?

[image]

Just to inform, some links I followed:

- http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide
- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: question is ... shouldn't be this aidl file in `/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing` ?

Comment: Gradle: Execution failed for task ':MyProject:compileDebugAidl'.
> Failed to run command:
45 interface IInAppBillingService should be declared in a file called com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl.

Comment: something tells me you're still not putting it in the folder that Selvin and I are saying...?

Comment: just added a new screenshot, I think I put it in the folder you told me..

Comment: http://selvin.pl/TrivialDriveProject.Gradle.zip (change sdk dir in local.properties) ... `gradlew.bat assemble` and it works like a charm ... are you sure that folder is /src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing not /src/main/aidl/com.android.vending.billing ? AS 0.2.1 ? Gradle 0.5.+ ?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I have the same issue here.

Comment: Sorry. I found my problem. It's still the path.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Just as the error message says, you need to put `IInAppBillingService.aidl` in the correct directory dictated by it's package (com.android.vending.billing).

Within the `src/main/aidl/` folder you already have, put the `.aidl` file in `com/android/vending/billing/`.

Comment: When I do this, I get: Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class IInAppBillingService

Comment: so it's in /src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing? Are you using gradle to build? If so, hit the little gradle button at the top right of Android Studio to have gradle reload configuration, or close/open Android Studio.

Comment: I used gradle to build, and updated screenshot shows you the folder in question

Comment: are you specifying a custom location for your aidl in your build.gradle?

Comment: Just to clarify. Create a directory aidl under src/main/. Then add a new package com.android.vending.billing. Then copy the aidl file into the new package. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56755

Comment: @Kalel Wade This was the solution for me, you should add it as an answer.

Comment: If you don't have src/main, create the aidl directory anywhere and specify in build.gradle: android { sourceSets { main { aidl { srcDirs 'actual_path..'

Comment: This doens't work for me. I allready have this structure and still get the same error.

Comment: If it's not working, you need to ACTUALLY MAKE the folders and not just create packages.

Answer (score 233):

Adding this as an answer since it seemed to help quite a few people.

1. **Create a new directory** named 'aidl' under 'src/main/'. It should look like '**src/main/aidl**'.
2. **Add a new package** name '**com.android.vending.billing**' to the directory '**src/main/aidl**'
3. Locate your sdk location and go to "sdk\extras\google\play_billing". Default location for the sdk is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk". If you custom changed it, then you will have to figure out the location through the sdk manager.
4. **Copy 'IInAppBillingService.aidl'** into the package created above. In the end, it should look similar to the image below.

[image: Screenshot of result]

5. **Rebuild** project and it should be good to go.

Note: Make sure you include the necessary import if your reference isn't working

```
import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;
```

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36973270

**Edit From Comment**

After I did this, the references to IInAppBillingService in my code were still highlighted as errors, but after rebuilding the app, the class was recognized

Comment: Just to be clear: read this thoroughly! I didn't...to emphasize again: It IS a good addition...PUT THE com.android.vending.billing IN THE NEW 'main/aidl' directory!

Comment: After I did this, the references to IInAppBillingService in my code were still highlighted as errors, but after rebuilding the app, the class was recognized.

Comment: This worked, but why isn't this all automatic, when you choose to add the module?

Comment: Thanks for the rebuild project tip. Also the folder and package can be created in a flavor, it doesn't have to be in main. (If for example you only do in app billing in one flavor of your app)

Comment: Spent 20 minutes trying to solve this problem until I came to your answer. Then I tried to upvote it to get the error "You last voted on this answer..." I guess some people never learn :)

Comment: I'd have given the green check to this answer for the illustration (worth a thousand words).

Comment: Can you tell me about step "3" ? I don't understand

Comment: @delive Step number 3 refers to the android sdk that is downloaded. I Believe the default location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk. It depends on what version you installed and if you changed it. Then navigate to the location in step 3 and get the file (step 4)

Comment: putting these 9 files in same directory with `MainActivity.class` worked for me! I didn't put them in `util` folder.

Comment: the aidl documentation says "save your .aidl file in your project's src/ directory and when you build your application, the SDK tools generate the IBinder interface file in your project's gen/ directory. The generated file name matches the .aidl file name, but with a .java extension". I got error on doing this, there is no gen folder I could see. Something told me there may be an aidl folder, which led me to this excellent answer, the error vanished.

Comment: This worked for me on android studio 4.2 C15 using SDK 30. Keep in mind after the rebuilt the error may take some time to go away 1-2min or so. so be patient!

Answer (score 12):

The rest of posts here didn't work for me till I created a **new folder** like shown here.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

- Create new directory under `src/main` called `aidl`
- Right click on directory `aidl`, select `new->add package`
- Enter Name of the package  `com.android.vending.billing`
- Copy `IInAppBillingService.aidl` from the directory `Android/Sdk/extras/google/play_billing` to the directory `App_name/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing`
- Now go ahead with InApp billing coding and while defining InApp related services you will get an error `can not resolve symbol IInAppBillingXXXXXX`
- Now goto to `Build` from android studio menu , click on `Rebuild Project`. This will generate `IInAppBillingService.java` file inside `App_Name/app/build/generated/source/aidl/debug/com/android/vending/billing`. This will solve the issue.

Comment: After copying file "IInAppBillingService.aidl", is it required to change any line of this file ? I have seen some notes asking to replace the package name as it is coming from a sample to avoid error "aidl.exe' finished with non-zero exit value 1". What are the specific instructions to do this ?

Answer (score 10):

Add this code in build.gradle

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```

Rebuild and import aidl class

Answer (score 6):

This answer might not exactly be for the question posted but may help others having issues related to creating `AIDL` folder. Sometimes the AIDL folder doesn't show in Android Studio even if we create like `app > New > Folder > AIDL Folder`. The folder exists in file explorer but doesn't show or detect in Android Studio.

I had this issue and I've solved it using the following steps

**Step 1:** Open the `gradle.properties` file and add the `android.defaults.buildfeatures.aidl=true` at the end of this file as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

**Step 2:** Right Click on the `app` folder it will show a window do the following flow `app > New > Folder > AIDL Folder`
[image]

**Step 3:** Click the Finish button
[image]
The `AIDL` folder is now created and shown in Android Studio
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The above answers concentrate on file location, but it appears you already had that set correctly.  I experienced this same issue in Android Studio, but none of the listed answers resolved it, and I banged my head against it for an hour.  Eventually, I realized that I was missing an obvious import:

```
 import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;
```

Once I added that it resolved this error message.

This import isn't mentioned in any of the Google Billing docs or included in any of the code examples that I found.  While it may be obvious to experienced Java developers, beginners just trying to learn their first project may need it explicitly pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

We need to add

1. create folder - src/main/aidl/packagename and place aidl file under this.
2. In the aidl file - mention the package name.
   package packagename

Now clean the project, rebuild the project - We can the corresponding java file for the aidl generated in app\build\generated\source\aidl\debug\packagename\youraidl.java

Answer (score 1):

I know it sounds so easy, but I copy paste from google sample all folder

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main

> aidl/com/android/vending/billing
>
> copied into project aidl ( I had set project view in Android Studio)

and next I clean and rebuild project and it found a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I use Android Studio 4.1, just right click mouse -> New -> AIDL -> AIDL File.
A file will be created and placed in the [src/main/aidl] folder automatically. The aidl folder will also be created if it does not exist.

This function only supports min sdk 16+. My old project still can be supported, you can temporarily modify the min sdk to 16, create aidl and build project. After the relative interface and class be generated, recover the min sdk settings, it also works and builds project well then.

Answer (score 1):

For gradle dsl add these lines to yours gradle.build.kts

```
sourceSets {
        getByName("main") {
            aidl.srcDirs("src/main/aidl")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried every solutions, but the problem was that Android Studio had compiled, with any apparent reason, in a different build type of the module that contains the AIDL packages than it was specified by the settings.
From **debug to release**, so the other modules couldn't see the AIDL pkg.
Switching from debug to release and turns back, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

restarting Android Studio worked for me

a second silly thing that took me a while. I dropped the code on Android Studio to allow him create the file, but he created a .java (as expected) instead a .aidl  Jiji, stupid of me

Answer (score 0):

if you do all the names correct go to Build>rebuild project
it worked for me