# In App Purchaes with Android Studio unable to find IInAppBillingService

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-billing

I am working on android project and I am using In App Purchases. It was all working in Eclipe but I saw Android Studio had another update which fixed a lot of issues related to library dependencies which does seem to be the case except for one problem. I am unable to use the IAP service as it keeps stating that it cannot be resolved to a symbol.

I have followed the instructions that someone posted here but unfortunately has not worked. Below are the links I have looked at

[how can I add the aidl file to Android studio (from the in-app billing example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836234/how-can-i-add-the-aidl-file-to-android-studio-from-the-in-app-billing-example)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56755

Below is a screenshot of my project structure and the error

[image: Screenshot of project structure and error]

Comment: Try to clean your build with gradlew clean and gradlew assemble and check your project.
You have an error also in R.

Comment: I solved with above comment,

Comment: One issue I ran into was I had copied the package `com.android.vending.billing` from Eclipse over to Android Studio into the wrong location, and it ended up changing the package name in the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file . I had to fix it manually

Answer (score 31):

as per info here:
[aidl files](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56160)

Aidl files are supposed to be in src/main/aidl: per the tools docs at:
[tools doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure)

Comment: This must be accepted as the right answer! I moved the package com.android.vending.billing with IInAppBillingService.aidl file into src/main/aidl directory and it compiled without any errors.

Comment: This document says nothing about aidl directory: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this error even though I placed the file in right directory and was importing it in right way. Then I just did `Build` > `Clean Project` and this solved the problem.

(As far as I can guess, not sure) I think when we add .aidl file at that time android studio doesn't know about it unless we compile our project at-least once

Answer (score 5):

In my case I just manually added import (after Gradle build):

```
import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;
```

Comment: First, you may need to do `Build` > `Clean Project`.

Answer (score 4):

2018

```
app/build.gradle:

sourceSets {
  main {
    aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
  }
}
```

for `IInAppBillingService.aidl`

Answer (score 0):

1.just create a package inside main dir (warning: Not inside app)
2.copy IInAppBillingService.aidl inside new package
3.clean project
4.rebuild project
5.import the package to neccesary class
Thats it Done buddy..................