# "error: cannot find symbol class IInAppBillingService"

Tags: android, android-studio, aidl

I have the same problem as this: 
[how can I add the aidl file to Android studio (from the in-app billing example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836234/how-can-i-add-the-aidl-file-to-android-studio-from-the-in-app-billing-example)

1. I have tried moving the file into different directories but it still says that it cannot resolve this.
2. I also tried syncing with gradle and the error still persists.
3. I've tried rebuilding the project as well :(

I am currently using Android Studio.

My current directory looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIVmC.png

Could anyone see if I did something wrong with the directory?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if your still having the issue, but looks like the issue is in your java folder, not the AIDL. Can you show the code of where the error is occuring?