# Implement Android Gesture Recognition Tool framework, receiving errors in generated build files

Tags: java, android, gesture, motion-detection

Im trying to use this [framework](http://www.dfki.de/~rnessel/tools/gesture_recognition/gesture_recognition.htm) for a school project. In order to install the framework it asks you to add a zip file to src. In the zip file I found a java class and some AIDL files. I follow the instructions on this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836234/how-can-i-add-the-aidl-file-to-android-studio-from-the-in-app-billing-example). When I try to clean and rebuild. I get a cannot resolve symbol class error. I would post error logs but am having trouble with my repo at the moment. The instructions online make it seem like you need to use the APK as well somehow but I have no idea how I would do that. Does anyone know or can figure out how this framework gets installed? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to use ***Android Studio 1.5*** instead of Eclipse and try to port the project from the website:

1. Execute and create **SVN working copy** (*android-gesture-recognition-tool* folder):

   ```
   svn checkout http://android-gesture-recognition-tool.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ android-gesture-recognition-tool
   ```

Notes:

(a) Android Studio supports checking out a SVN project using its `Checkout from Version Control` project wizard...However, the project above does not have any `build.gradle` file

(b) You can use **TortoiseSVN** tool available from Internet to create the SVN working copy

2. From ***Android Studio*** new project wizard:

   Start a New Android Project

   ```
   Configure Your New Project:
       type Application Name: Gesture Trainer
       type Company Domain: android.dfki.de

   Select the Form Factors...:
       check Phone and Tablet
       select Minimum SDK: API 8

   Add an Activity to Mobile:
       choose Blank Activity

   Customize the Activity:
       type Activity Name: Gesture Trainer

   Let Gradle finishes its job
   ```
3. Close ***Android Studio***
4. From the ***Android Studio***'s  generated **GestureTrainer** project folder:

   ```
   Open GestureTrainer/app/src folder:
       delete androidTest folder
       delete test folder

   Open GestureTrainer/app/src/main folder:
       delete every folder in it
       copy res folder from the SVN working copy into it
       copy assets folder from the SVN working copy into it
       copy src folder from the SVN working copy into it
       copy AndroidManifest.xml from the SVN working copy into it
       create aidl folder in it
   ```
5. Open ***Android Studio***; from **Gesture Trainer** project in ***Android Studio*** environment:

   ```
   Clean Project

   Rebuild Project
       Ignore the errors for a while

   Go to app/src/main/aidl Android project tree
       Right click on aidl and select New > Package
           Type a new package: de.dfki.ccaal.gestures
       Right click on aidl and select New > Package
           Type a new package: de.dfki.ccaal.gestures.classifier
   ```
6. From the generated **GestureTrainer** project folder:

   ```
   Copy into GestureTrainer/app/src/aidl/de/dfki/ccaal/gestures folder:
       IGestureRecognitionListener.aidl from SVN working copy
       IGestureRecognitionService.aidl from SVN working copy

   Copy into GestureTrainer/app/src/aidl/de/dfki/ccaal/gestures/classifier folder:
       Distribution.aidl from SVN working copy
   ```
7. Modify `app/build.gradle` file from **Gesture Trainer** project in ***Android Studio*** environment as follows:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "de.dfki.android.gestureTrainer"
           minSdkVersion 8
           targetSdkVersion 23
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
   }
   ```
8. Restart ***Android Studio*** and let Gradle resync the project...

You should get something as in the following figure:

[image]

Comment: What if I want to use the Gesture Trainer in an application I've already built?

Comment: I added it to my existing application by following these instructions and it worked as well. You still need to have the framework files in the de.dfk packages tho.