# android inapp billing error IInAppBillingService.aidl

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I'm implementing billing in app and getting following error while building project.

> C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Blessd\app\src\main\aidl\IInAppBillingService.aidl:46 interface IInAppBillingService should be declared in a file called com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl.

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836234/how-can-i-add-the-aidl-file-to-android-studio-from-the-in-app-billing-example?rq=1

Comment: thanks so much will have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not copy the IInAppBillingService.aidl in your own directory(**aidl\IInAppBillingService.aidl**). It should be there in this directory only.

```
com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl
```

Comment: thanks to you and solar for the assistance SO needs more of you guys. I created a new package under app > src > main > aidl, and moved the file into that package in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This Screenshot can help you without any words !
also, DO NOT FORGET TO CHANGE PACKAGE NAME OT .AIDL file TO YOUR OWN PACKAGE FILe.

[image]