# import android.app.job.IJobScheduler cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, scheduler

I am trying to set up data synchronization between android application and server (with WCF data services) in background using Job Scheduler (according to [this](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/how-to-schedule-background-tasks-in-android-apps-using-the-jobscheduler-api.html) article).

After all settled (as described in the article) the execution failed on missing reference to **android.app.job.IJobScheduler** (It was called from JobSchedulerImpl.java). These are **android-studio system files**. Maybe some update has to be installed, but I could not find the right one. 
[image]

Please consult on how to solve this.

I found close question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836234/how-can-i-add-the-aidl-file-to-android-studio-from-the-in-app-billing-example), but it is not solving my issue.