# Adding .aidl interafce in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aidl

I have two .adil interface in a specific aidl folder but then also It is not recognizing my file.I have followed these steps:
[I have followed these steps in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836234/how-can-i-add-the-aidl-file-to-android-studio-from-the-in-app-billing-example/17836495)

My .aidl file is:

```
interface IControllerInterface {
/**
 * Init IPCController.
 * @param cmd_type Only support Wearable SDK Controller CMD_8 or CMD_9
 * @param tagName Controller Tag
 */
int init(int cmd_type, in String tagName);

/**
 * Send bytes to Wearable.
 * @param tagName Controller Tag, use your IPCController init tag.
 * @param cmd command string, like "yahooweather yahooweather 1 0 0 "
 * @param dataBuffer byte type of data, like "".getBytes()
 * @param priority default PRIORITY_NORMAL, if set as PRIORITY_HIGH, this session
 *        will get top priority to send.
 */
long sendBytes(in String tagName, String cmd, in byte[] data, int priority);

/**
 * Return connection state.
 * 
 * @see WearableManager#STATE_NONE
 * @see WearableManager#STATE_LISTEN
 * @see WearableManager#STATE_CONNECT_FAIL
 * @see WearableManager#STATE_CONNECT_LOST
 * @see WearableManager#STATE_CONNECTING
 * @see WearableManager#STATE_CONNECTED
 * @see WearableManager#STATE_DISCONNECTING
 */
int getConnectionState();

/**
 * Destroy the IPCController.
 */
void close(String tagName);

/**
 * register IControllerCallback for the "tagName" IPCController.
 */
void registerControllerCallback(in String tagName, in IControllerCallback callback);

/**
 * unregister IControllerCallback for the "tagName" IPCController.
 */
void unregisterControllerCallback(in String tagName, in IControllerCallback callback);

/**
 * get SmartDevice APK remote Bluetooth device Name.
 */
String getRemoteDeviceName();
```

}

This is my class where I need to extend it:

```
private class ControllerBinder extends IControllerInterface.Stub {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with [Android Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl#java). And found the root cause of my problem.I the above posted  code there is another aidl interface being used in my case. **IControllerInterface** is not able to find **IControllerCallback** interface.
Please let me know how to access one aidlinterface into another aidl interface.

Comment: you need to import IControllerCallback into IControllerInterface.aidl file with fully given package name